# Writing custom functions in Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following snippet in my Helm deployment yaml file:

```
{{if or .Values.ha.enabled .Values.checkpointing.enable_checkpointing .Values.enable_upgrade_hook}}
{{if eq .Values.pvc.file_prefix "file://"}}
- mountPath: {{ .Values.pvc.shared_storage_path }}/{{ template "fullname" . }}
  name: shared-pvc
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

I would like to put all these *if* checks into a custom function and just call the function here. My new snippet using the function should look like this:

```
{{if eq enable_mount_volume "true"}}
- mountPath: {{ .Values.pvc.shared_storage_path }}/{{ template "fullname" . }}
  name: shared-pvc
{{end}}
```

How would I achieve this? I may have multiple deployment yaml files, each doing this conditional check, and it would be useful to just call a function instead of  putting the logic-heavy if check in each yaml file(Just to make it less error-prone).

Also, I wouldn't want to define this function in every single template file, as that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: use the file  `_helpers.tpl`  to encapsulate your conditions using functions and calling them by `{{ template "funcName" }}`. See the docs for details.

Comment: I guess there is no support for custom functions?
It seems a Go-implemented function needs to be registered in a `FuncMap`, but a) where to define that function, where to put that file containing it and finally where to register it in a `FuncMap`?

Comment: I read somewhere that `.Funcs` (or `.Func` maybe?) can be used to register new functions; sorry I can't provide a link.

Comment: You cannot define real custom functions, but work around it by defining *procedure like* templates. I have written a bit about it in [Are Helm Charts Turing-Complete?](https://dastrobu.medium.com/are-helm-charts-turing-complete-46ea7a540ca2)

Answer (score 7):

You can create a [partial template](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-partials-and-template-includes) named *conditional-mount* in a file starting with underscore, for example, `templates/_conditional-mount.tpl`:

```
{{define "conditional-mount"}}
{{if or .Values.ha.enabled .Values.checkpointing.enable_checkpointing .Values.enable_upgrade_hook}}
{{if eq .thisPvc.file_prefix "file://"}}
- mountPath: {{ .thisPvc.shared_storage_path }}/{{ template "fullname" . }}
  name: shared-pvc
{{end}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```

And then use it you anywhere you need via:

```
{{include "conditional-mount" (dict "Values" .Values "thisPvc" .Values.pvc)}}
```

The trick here is that you specify a pvc to be mounted via the scope object **thisPvc** pointing to the **.Values.pvc**. The [Sprig dict function](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/dicts.md) is used.
You can then call it for different PVC, for example, `.Values.pvcXYZ`:

```
{{include "conditional-mount" (dict "Values" .Values "thisPvc" .Values.pvcXYZ)}}
```

Comment: The `partial template` URL returns a 404.

Comment: The new URL is https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-partials-and-template-includes (the original answer updated as well) @Akito.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [`{{template "foo"}}` or `{{block "foo"}}`](https://godoc.org/text/template#hdr-Nested_template_definitions) will do what you want, depending on a huge number "what ifs".

The [helm docs](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#declaring-and-using-templates-with-define-and-template) have a **lot** more words around that very problem, which is great because they have obviously considered it, and sad because whew what a lot of words.